# Android Spinner Radiobutton view doesn't respond until you scroll the spinner

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner

I have a Spinner in one screen that is setup like this:

```
    defScreenSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.default_screen);
adapter =
  new SimpleAdapter(v.getContext(), data, R.layout.image_spinner_item, new String[] { "image" },
    new int[] { R.id.image }) {
    private View[] views = new View[data.size()];

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      Log.d(TAG, "getDropDownView: " + position);
      View v = views[position];

      if (v == null) {
        // Need unique views so Radio buttons can be tracked individually
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_spinner_item, null);

        Map<String, Object> map = data.get(position);
        int imgresid = (Integer) map.get("image");
        boolean selected = (position == defScreenIdx);
        Log.d(TAG,
              String.format("populateView: position=%d, resid=%d, sel=%d", position, imgresid, (selected ? 1 : 0)));
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        iv.setImageResource(imgresid);
        RadioButton cb = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.selectedimg);
        cb.setChecked(selected);
        cb.setTag(position);
        if (selected) {
          curButton = cb;
        }
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Button Clicked: " + isChecked);
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
              onSelDefault(buttonView);
            }
          }
        });

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "View Clicked: ");
          }
        });

        views[position] = v;
      }

      return v;
    }
  };
defScreenSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
defScreenSpinner.setBackgroundResource(imgIds.get(defScreenIdx));
defScreenSpinner.setSelection(defScreenIdx);

...

  public void onSelDefault(View v) {
    if (curButton != null) {
      curButton.setChecked(false);
      curButton.invalidate();
    }
    curButton = (RadioButton) v;
    curButton.setChecked(true);
    defScreenIdx = (Integer) v.getTag();
    Log.d(TAG, "defIdx=" + defScreenIdx);
    defScreenSpinner.setBackgroundResource(imgIds.get(defScreenIdx));
    defScreenSpinner.setSelection(defScreenIdx);
    return;
    }
```

The Spinner button looks fine, and when you click in the Spinner panel comes up.
The problem is that the Radio buttons don't work at all - until you scroll the view.
When I first click on the Spinner button, the log shows this:

```
11-04 08:42:04.831: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 0
11-04 08:42:04.831: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): populateView: position=0, resid=2130837697, sel=1
11-04 08:42:04.831: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 1
11-04 08:42:04.841: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): populateView: position=1, resid=2130837715, sel=0
11-04 08:42:04.841: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 2
11-04 08:42:04.841: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): populateView: position=2, resid=2130837725, sel=0
11-04 08:42:04.841: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 3
11-04 08:42:04.851: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): populateView: position=3, resid=2130837640, sel=0
11-04 08:42:04.851: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 4
11-04 08:42:04.851: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): populateView: position=4, resid=2130837721, sel=0
11-04 08:42:04.851: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 5
11-04 08:42:04.862: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): populateView: position=5, resid=2130837513, sel=0
11-04 08:42:04.862: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 6
11-04 08:42:04.862: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): populateView: position=6, resid=2130837507, sel=0
11-04 08:42:04.881: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 0
11-04 08:42:04.881: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 1
11-04 08:42:04.881: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 2
11-04 08:42:04.881: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 3
11-04 08:42:04.891: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 4
11-04 08:42:04.891: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 5
11-04 08:42:04.891: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 6
11-04 08:42:04.891: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 0
11-04 08:42:04.891: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 1
11-04 08:42:04.891: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 2
11-04 08:42:04.891: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 3
11-04 08:42:04.891: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 4
11-04 08:42:04.891: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 5
11-04 08:42:04.901: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 0
11-04 08:42:04.901: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 1
11-04 08:42:04.901: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 2
11-04 08:42:04.901: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 3
11-04 08:42:04.911: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 4
11-04 08:42:04.911: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 5
11-04 08:42:04.911: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 6
11-04 08:42:04.921: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 0
11-04 08:42:04.921: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 1
11-04 08:42:04.921: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 2
11-04 08:42:04.931: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 3
11-04 08:42:04.931: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 4
11-04 08:42:04.931: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 5
11-04 08:42:04.931: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 6
11-04 08:42:13.646: D/PreferencesActivity(6236): getDropDownView: 6
```

So, it builds the first 7 radio buttons, and selects the first one.
So I then click on buttons 2 through 4.  NOTHING shows up in the log.
Next I scroll the view all the way down and back to the top.
Log shows:

```
11-04 09:09:52.662: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 6
11-04 09:09:52.662: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 7
11-04 09:09:52.671: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=7, resid=2130837707, sel=0
11-04 09:09:52.701: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 8
11-04 09:09:52.701: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=8, resid=2130837709, sel=0
11-04 09:09:52.701: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 9
11-04 09:09:52.721: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=9, resid=2130837653, sel=0
11-04 09:09:52.721: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 10
11-04 09:09:52.721: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=10, resid=2130837705, sel=0
11-04 09:09:52.721: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 11
11-04 09:09:52.732: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=11, resid=2130837651, sel=0
11-04 09:09:52.912: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 12
11-04 09:09:52.912: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=12, resid=2130837514, sel=0
11-04 09:09:52.932: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 13
11-04 09:09:52.932: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=13, resid=2130837677, sel=0
11-04 09:09:52.942: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 14
11-04 09:09:52.961: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=14, resid=2130837717, sel=0
11-04 09:09:53.042: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 15
11-04 09:09:53.042: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=15, resid=2130837593, sel=0
11-04 09:09:53.072: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 16
11-04 09:09:53.072: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=16, resid=2130837689, sel=0
11-04 09:09:53.082: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 17
11-04 09:09:53.092: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): populateView: position=17, resid=2130837712, sel=0
11-04 09:09:53.092: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 13
11-04 09:09:53.092: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 12
11-04 09:09:54.762: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 11
11-04 09:09:54.802: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 10
11-04 09:09:54.862: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 9
11-04 09:09:54.862: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 8
11-04 09:09:54.872: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 7
11-04 09:09:54.952: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 6
11-04 09:09:54.952: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 5
11-04 09:09:54.952: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 4
11-04 09:09:55.092: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 3
11-04 09:09:55.092: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 2
11-04 09:09:55.111: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 1
11-04 09:09:55.111: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 0
11-04 09:09:55.111: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): getDropDownView: 5
```

A single click on the 2nd button causes these log entries: (It appears that my previous clicks were all queued up and waiting for something...)

```
11-04 09:10:56.248: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): Button Clicked: true
11-04 09:10:56.248: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): Button Clicked: false
11-04 09:10:56.252: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): defIdx=1
11-04 09:10:56.325: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): Button Clicked: true
11-04 09:10:56.325: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): Button Clicked: false
11-04 09:10:56.325: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): defIdx=2
11-04 09:10:56.332: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): Button Clicked: true
11-04 09:10:56.332: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): Button Clicked: false
11-04 09:10:56.332: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): defIdx=3
11-04 09:10:56.352: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): Button Clicked: true
11-04 09:10:56.352: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): Button Clicked: false
11-04 09:10:56.352: D/PreferencesActivity(6262): defIdx=4
```

and now the 5th button (idx = 4) is selected.

From now on, any clicks on any of the buttons work just fine.  The button is selected, and the old button is deselected.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are caching the `View`s. Don't do that. The spinner recycles the `View`s itself, so your caching of them creates a conflict. You need to look at the `ViewHolder` pattern that is commonly used in Android and also understand how to use the recycled `View` (the `convertView` argument) properly.

Comment: Yup.  Hadn't even noticed it was doing that. (old code I inherited. bleh.)  Once I started using the convertView properly, the hard part was getting the old Radio Button to uncheck.  Ended up using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged to cause the list to be updated.